# How to blcok websites using Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Is it possible to create a Flutter app that blocks popular gambling websites when the app is running, similar to ad blocking solutions?

Background:
I am interested in creating a Flutter app that blocks popular gambling websites when the app is running. I am wondering if this is possible, and if so, how it could be done. I am thinking of something similar to ad blocking solutions, which use a list of known ad domains to block those ads from loading.

Question:
Is it possible to create a Flutter app that blocks popular gambling websites when the app is running?
If so, how could this be done?
Are there any existing Flutter packages or resources that I could use for this?
Additional details:
I am interested in blocking both gambling websites and gambling apps. I would also like to be able to update the list of blocked websites and apps on a regular basis.

Example:
The user opens the Flutter app and starts browsing the web. When the user tries to visit a gambling website, the app blocks the website from loading. The user is then shown a message explaining that the website is blocked.
One possible solution is to use a web proxy to block the gambling websites. The Flutter app could connect to the web proxy and send all of its web traffic through the proxy. The proxy would then block any requests to gambling websites.

Answer (score -3):

## In your pubspec.yaml file, add the necessary package for handling web content:

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
webview_flutter: ^2.0.15  # Add the latest version of the webview_flutter package.
```

## Then run flutter pub get to install the package.

```
fluuter pub get
```

## In your Flutter app, use the webview_flutter package to display web content.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
home: Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('Website Blocker App'),
),
body: WebView(
initialUrl: 'https://example.com', // Initial URL (change as needed)
javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
),
),
);
}
}
```

## To block specific websites, you'll need to intercept and inspect network requests. The webview_flutter package doesn't provide a direct way to do this, so you'll need to use a workaround.

```
 class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_WebViewPageState createState() => _WebViewPageState();
}

class _WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {
final Set<String> blockedUrls = {'https://blocked-site.com'}; // Add blocked URLs

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('Website Blocker App'),
),
body: WebView(
initialUrl: 'https://example.com', // Initial URL (change as needed)
javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
onPageFinished: (url) {
if (blockedUrls.contains(url)) {
// Replace the current page with a safe page or display a message
webView.loadUrl('https://safe-page.com');
}
},
),
);
}
}
```

Note that this is a simplified example and may not work perfectly for all scenarios.